# Xamarin Tutorial from docs.microsoft with some additions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hello I am trying to make my first AndroidApp with Xamarin.  I used the tutorial from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android-multiscreen/hello-android-multiscreen-quickstart?pivots=windows but instead of the method that converts letters into numbers I made a simple method to reverse the string from the input field.

My activity_main.axml has the following controls:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Input Text:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:id="@+id/TextToReverse" />
<Button
    android:text="Reverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextToReverse"
    android:id="@+id/ReverseBtn" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="34.5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ReverseBtn"
    android:id="@+id/ReversedText" />
<Button
    android:text="History"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ReversedText"
    android:id="@+id/HistoryBtn"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

My MainActivity.cs

```
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            List<string> reversedStringsMain = new List<string>();

            //find UI elements by id
            EditText textToRev = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.TextToReverse);
            TextView reversedText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ReversedText);
            Button reverseBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ReverseBtn);
            Button historyBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.HistoryBtn);

            reverseBtn.Click += (sender, e) => 
            {
                string output = ReverseMethod.Reverse(textToRev.Text);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
                {
                    reversedText.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    reversedText.Text = output;
                    reversedStringsMain.Add(textToRev.Text);
                    historyBtn.Enabled = true;
                }

            };

            historyBtn.Click += (sender, e) => 
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(History));
                intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("reversed_strings", reversedStringsMain);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
```

So here I have an array that saves all the strings I have already reversed and a history button event that shows the list of the reversed strings.

I have created a new ListActivity with the following code:

```
 base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            var reversedStrings = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("reversed_strings") ?? new string[0];
            this.ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, reversedStrings);


            ListView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
            {
                //code that I don't know how to make
                EditText textToReverse = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.TextToReverse);
                textToReverse.Text =  MainActivity.reversedStringsMain[args.Position]; //here I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."                       

            };
```

My goal is to make the items from the list clickable and when I click them I want the input filed from the main activity to get the value of the item I have clicked.

I also want to add a button on the second screen to Clear the whole list.

Comment: I posted my whole code so that it is a little bit more clear what  I am trying to do. I hope I it is not much confusing

Comment: Is `reversedStringsMain` in your `MainActivity` static? And are you sure there is an instance of `MainActivity` in the background? Why are you passing in the strings in Intent extras to your HistoryActivity if you are not using them and using the ones from the `MainActivity` instance?

Comment: yeah reversedStringsMain is static in my MainActivity and how can I be sure if there is an instance of MainActivity in the background? And about the `intent` im not exactly sure how it works but I used the code from the tutorial

Comment: The issue is that you _can't_ be sure there is an instance. Hence, it is a _very_ bad idea to use a static in an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass some data from `HistoryActivity` back to `MainActivity`, you should not refer to `MainActivity` directly or save data in static variables, but rather

Start `HistoryActivity` with a [`StartActivityForResult`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult/p/Android.Content.Intent/System.Int32/) method:

```
historyBtn.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(History));
    intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("reversed_strings", reversedStringsMain);
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 2);
};
```

[Finish](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.Finish/) a `HistoryActivity` with a result:

```
ListView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HistoryActivity)); 
    intent.PutExtra("position", args.Position); 
    SetResult(Result.Ok, intent); 
    Finish();
}
```

Override [`OnActivityResult`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult/) of `MainActivity` to read data from passed intent:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (resultCode)
    {
        case Result.Ok:
            var position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
            var selectedString = reversedStringsMain[position];
            // fill in input field in MainActivity
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and where do I get mIntent from?

Comment: Actually it worked. I had to make some minor changes to it. Thanks a lot. I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Could you also tell me how can I add a button underneath the history. I want to make a clear button to clear the history.

Comment: If you've chosen to inherit from `ListActivity`, there is no xaml to inflate. You should look into a floating action button, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android as an example.

Comment: ok I will take a look at it. And could you tell if it is possible to make a new layout axml file to display the history and the  clear button there?

Comment: Yes, you can inherit a `HistoryActivity` from an ordinary Activity, and inflate an axml layout with `ListView` and a button.

Comment: could you recomment me a good tutorial for layoutInflater because Im trying to make it work, but so far I haven't managed to.